# How can I add "Tabelle" before the numbering at the list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

Compiler: XeLatex on Overleaf

I am now writing a template for my master thesis. I need to do this.
[image]

I have already tried several approaches, but it does not work.

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{Tabelle}}}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\textbf{Tabelle}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{table}:\enspace}}
```

This code does change the table name in the work, but at the list of tables it is still x.x, but not Tabelle x.x.

But the same code does work on the list of figures.

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Bild}}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{figure}:\enspace}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please share  your setup with us. For example, the fact that you use `\cfttabpresnum` suggests that you are using the `tocloft` package. That's the kind of information we need in order to answer. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917).

Comment: Note that `\tablename` should as the name suggest only contain the name, no formatting like here `\textbf`. If the visual representation of `\tablename` should be in bold then consult the feature that typesets it, for example the class, of which you give no information.

Comment: First things first: What document class are you even using? Please share a minimal working example (MWE) with us.

Comment: See the `tocloft` package. As you have not provided an MWE I can't think of anything specific for you except that `tocloft` handles many changes to the ToC and friends.